# How to display the average price of bitcoin in Pandas and not through a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
y = []
n = 0
days = 1
for i in btc['Adj Close']:
    averagePrice = (i + n) / days
    n += i
    days += 1
    y.append(averagePrice)

btc['TopAverage'] = y
```

Comment: Use code fences to get code syntax. Three backticks. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: can you share a complete description of your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If `btc` is a pandas data frame (as it appears so), then:

```
btc.loc[:, 'Days'] = list(range(1, btc.shape[0] + 1))
btc.loc[:, 'n'] = btc['Adj Close'].cumsum().shift(periods=1, fill_value=0.)
btc.loc[:, 'TopAverage'] = (btc['Adj Close'] + btc['n']) / btc['Days']
```

reflects the logic in your code. This will add the columns `'Days'` and `'n'` to the data frame as well.